# How to return Vlookup value when one of the criteria is date

Tags: excel

[image]

Hi,

Could you please help -If I have a table of starting and ending date, how to return the value of % required per person for a given date?. If this will make huge difference in the formula could you please respond with 2 cases.
1. When we have additional column -active/not so we can use sumproduct  or sumifs for exa (I tried with sumproduct , but didnt work here
2. If we might have duplicate entries, so sums functions can't be used

Thank you

Comment: Am I just not understanding? - Couldn't you just use `SUMIFS()` with G2 & 3/4 being your criteria, B & C being your criteria range and D being your sum range???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following array formula:

```
=INDEX($D$3:$D$8,MATCH(1,(($A$3:$A$8<=$G$2)*($B$3:$B$8>=$G$2)*($C$3:$C$8=G3)*($E$3:$E$8="active")),0))
```

You need to enter the above with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The `MATCH` will fetch the first row number within the table range where all the conditions are met, namely that the date is within the range, the person and whether they are active or not.

Comment: Thank you, Jerry, did it work for you? For me for some reason is not working . And yes, John, I tried sumifs but didnt work. Is it possible the date format to behave funny in this case or normally should work?

Comment: @user3430920 Yes, it's working for me, but I changed the date to `30/06/2006` because the 31st of June isn't a valid date. Also make sure you're using Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: That the OP has `31/6/2014` in his cell suggest that the "dates" are in fact strings

Comment: Thank you very much Jerry. Can I elaborate the example.Instead of having "active" and "not" is there any way when the lookup will fetch the last example on the row under certain criteria? (as per above example, if we didnt have "active/not" column and in cell D7 the value was 7, is there a way so the formula would return 7 for natali for 30/06/2006 (if we presume that the latest information is being put below the previous one )